# Doctrine and memory

Tags: php, symfony, memory-leaks, doctrine-orm

```php
    dump("Before Memory: " . LogUtility::getMemoryUsage());
    $this->_em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);
    $start = $i*self::COUNT;
    $entityName = $this->getEntityName();

    $query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()->select("c")->from($entityName, "c");
    $query->setFirstResult($start);
    $query->setMaxResults(self::COUNT);
    $query = $query->getQuery();
    $query->useQueryCache(false);
    $query->useResultCache(false);


    $result = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT);
    //$query->expireQueryCache(true);
    //unset($result);

    for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++):
        $this->_em->detach($result[$i]);
    endfor;
    $this->_em->clear();
    @$query = null;
    @$result = null;
    unset($query,$result);

    dump("After Memory: " . LogUtility::getMemoryUsage());
```

Hey Im becoming crazy with this code, I am trying to free memory after this doctrine call of around 5000 entities but it won't free memory and I really don't understand why.

```
"Before Memory: 19.5 mb"
"After Memory: 80 mb"
```

I tried detaching, clearing, unsetting, destruct function, the free function, using the sqllogger, the cache, Im becoming completely mad right now !
Plus If I use the HYDRATE_ARRAY I can easily unset the var and free memory and but when its about object, this becomes a problem. My related entities all have the detach cascade operation and yea In case you asking me if the way I report memory is good heres the function

```
 static public function getMemoryUsage() {
        $size = memory_get_usage(true);
        $unit=array('b','kb','mb','gb','tb','pb');
        $size = @round($size/pow(1024,($i=floor(log($size,1024)))),2).'    '.$unit[$i];
    return $size;
}
```

Thanks for your help this is driving me crazy !! Ohh and also, this is run from a command line calling a controller who fetches a repository,
the controller is as simple as that

```
 __construct(EntityManager $em, Logger $logger);

public function executeAction (){
     $this->repo->updateData(0);
}
```

EDIT: Also tried using gc_collect_cycles() , no difference

EDIT2: I need the object because Im about to update it. Otherwise would have taken the array and the problem would have been solved

EDIT3: Also cleared the log folder, I am running out of options and I can't afford the memory not being freed because the script will update 50k Entities.

```
========================== SOLUTION ==================================

 $iterableResult= $query->iterate();
    foreach ($iterableResult as $row) {
         $this->_em->detach($row[0]);
    }

"Memory: 19.5 mb"
"Memory: 34.5 mb"
```

The solution is in the iterate function that must have some sort of mechanism thats make it work !! So basically, dont think its only a detach, you MUST use the iterate class of doctrine for this bash processing to works !! Now theres 10Mb overhead but Im not gonna  pull my hair off to understand where it went. Anyways, there you go guys ! When doctrine gives you a way to do it, COPY it !! Anyhow, if someone could explain us why the iterate function has that special magic, it would be great for other people that went through the same struggle I had.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html

Comment: I had something like that problem with memory overflow with doctrine odm and very big set of data, it took ~4GB of memory and my script gone down. I stucked with that for several days and almost got crazy so in the end I rewrote with native driver functions I had minimum memory usage and it cleaned memory smoothly.

Comment: It porobably went to circular references and partialy this is how GC in PHP works.

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine2 is known to have some memory leaks during long operations. See [this blogpost](https://coderwall.com/p/awzjhw/avoiding-memory-leaks-in-symfony2-doctrine-entitymanager), for example

In my case, disabling logger saved me some memory, but not all.

```
$this->em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);
```